# server caching problem on ASP.NET MVC page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have server caching error on ASP.NET MVC Pages.
The scenario is like this.

I have two applications (1).External Website and (2).Internal Adminsite, both pointing to the same Database.

There is one page called **EditProfile Page** on the **External Website** that registered customer can update his profile information like Firstname, Lastname and Address…etc.
Similarly there is similar functionality on the **Internal Adminsite** on the page called **CustomerProfile Page** where the Site Admin can update all these fields.

When the user updates the profile information from the Adminsite, those updates are not reflecting back to the Website.

Now I tried restarting the Website on IIS and that din’t help.
Again I tried both **restarting the Website** on IIS and **opening a new browser**, then those updates are reflecting back.

I am wondering how I can come out of this caching problem without restarting the site and open a new browser window everytime? Are there any **IIS settings** that could help?

This caching is happening only on couple of tables only and all the updates are showing up in the database.

Appreciate your responses.

Thanks

Comment: What is the architecture of your application? Do you have caching turned on on the Page? Are you storing values in session or profile? Do you have any proxy servers between your browser and server?

Comment: No. The caching is not turned on the Page. I am storing only the UserName in the session. There are no Proxy servers between Browser and server.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the page is being cached by the browser. Try an http debugger like http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to check the cache headers sent with the response.